# exceptions Python HTTPSConnection

Tags: python, exception

I'm trying to make exceptions for
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection (site, timeout = 5)
when it exceeds the timeout. What exception should I use?

```
try:
            conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(site, timeout=5)
            conn.request("GET", "/")
            except http.client.NotConnected as e:
            cprint("%-30s %-50s %-10s %-30s %-20s" %(time.strftime("%c"),site, st,rs,elapse_time),'red')
```

I have never handled exceptions and I require that it not be stopped for the time of the website.

the code is the following

```
while 1:
    cantT=0
    for site in SITES:
            #prueba
            #conn = urllib.request.urlopen(site)
            #conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(site, timeout=10)
            #Variables de conexion y estado
        try:
            conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(site, timeout=5)
            conn.request("GET", "/")
            response = conn.getresponse()
            rs = response.reason
            st = str (response.status)
            cantT+= 1
            #se calcula el tiempo transcurido para el check
            inicio = time.time()
            elapse_time = str(time.time()-inicio)
            if response.status == 200:
                cprint("%-30s %-50s %-10s %-30s %-20s" %(time.strftime("%c"),site, st,rs,elapse_time),'green')
```

Comment: Python is sensitive to correct indentation, which seems to be your problem

Comment: yes, correctly the indentation is a subject to be corrected. but is it normal for the error to be syntax and not indentation?
I have already indented a bit the code on all the part of the while and the try without success .. it continues giving syntax error in the expect

Comment: I think the `expect` is expected at the same level than the `try`. But I have written zero lines of Python, so I'm not sure

Comment: correct! thanks, I let it pass.

Now it is to see which is the exception that works for the timeout, or to be able to make a conditional. but I do not have how to measure it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was required to use the following exception as urllib.

```
except (http.client.HTTPException, socket.timeout, socket.error):
```